# Click Link using Robot Framework doesn't work with Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm new with Robot Framework. I made couple of scripts, that I have tested with Chrome and Firefox. With Chrome everything works fine, but with Firefox I have one tricky problem. I try to click link called ***Post*** like this:

```
Click Link link=Post
```

With Firefox it won't work and I just get following error:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message:

In Chrome, this same test is working fine.

- Firefox version is 53.0.3 (64-bit).
- Selenium Driver version: 3.4.3
- Geckodriver version:  0.16.1

Any suggestions? What can I try?

Comment: When I was making tests, I sometimes ran into this issue. And the only way I figured out was to use different locators until all the browsers (Edge, Chrome, FF) accepted it. Try using different locators (Xpath, Name, etc)

Comment: Problem is, that I can't see anything, what I can crab from that link. Link in HTML-looks like this:

`<a href="https://post.myserver.com">Post</a>`

Comment: Why not `Click Link | href=https://post.myserver.com` If not use the Xpath

Comment: Do you possibly have two links that match `link=Post` on the page? Perhaps the first one it is finding is not the one you think it is.

Comment: I have tried both of these:

`Click Link    href=https://post.myserver.com`
`Click Link    xpath=//a[@href="https://post.myserver.com"]`

But Bryan is right. There are two Post links. Other one is for mobile devices. In page source it seems to be the first one, that I should click. How to do that?

Comment: then use `xpath=//a[@href="https://post.myserver.com"][1]` or `[2]` cant remember exactly. Basically you want to point to the the correct one. so if the post youre looking for is the 1st ont he list use `[1]` else its the second so use `[2]`

Comment: Well the problem is, that with xpath clicking link won't work:

_Valid Login                                                           | FAIL |
ElementNotInteractableException: Message:_

Comment: Have this problem too, no other matching elements on the page, only works with <xpath> [1], tried css, id and path selectors. Mouse Over and Focus work, meaning the element can kinda be found, but it cannot be interacted... earlier when I tried to verify the element (a -link) contents, the text was '' (empty string) all the time. Using Robot 3.02 + gecko driver 0.18, Firefox 55.0.3 ... could be a issue with newest FF, not newest gecko driver (0.19 is) combo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Click Element  xpath=(//a[text()='Post'])[1]
```

or there will be different class for mobile and web I guess. 
You can add these to narrow down on single element out of two. 
Something like:

```
Click Element  xpath=//a[text()='Post']/parent::div[contains(@class,'web')]
```